# How to find the selected item on Listbox in OnLbnSelchange() event win32 prouject c++?

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox, win32gui

I am working on a win32 project c++ project; 
On a dialog I have a listbox; for retrieving which item is selected I want to complete the ONLBNSELCHANGE() event ;

but there is no example on the net. also I tried to use the GetDlgItem() function but when I pass it two parameters include one handle and the control ID this error occurs:

> no instance of overloaded function "CMarkerList::GetDlgItem" matches
>   the argument list argument types are: (HWND,int)

How can I write this event?

thank you so much!

Comment: From [the MSDN `CListBox` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9.aspx): "**ON_LBN_SELCHANGE** ... This notification applies only to a list box that has the LBS_NOTIFY style." So the question is, do your listbox have the `LBS_NOTIFY` style set?

Comment: `CWnd::GetDlgItem` has only one argument. Just write `GetDlgItem(your_listbox_id).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls already have the methods built into them that you need.

1. Select the listbox on your form in the dialog editor, and right click and select add variable, then give your listbox a name like m_MYListbox;  This will declare the listbox control in the header of your dialog class.
2. Go back to the form editor and double click the selected listbox.  This will generate the correct OnLbnSelChangexxx handler for the control.
3. Once you've done this you can easily get the selected item and its contents inside the handler

   ```
   CMyDlg::OnLbnSelchangeMyListbox()
   {
   CString theData;
    // get the selected position of the listbox
    UINT uiSelection = m_MYListbox.GetCurSel(); 

   if (uiSelection == LB_ERR) return;


   m_MYListbox.GetText(uiSelection,theData);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you so much! it works Well;) can you suggest me some tutorial to know more about win32 programming? Regards!

Comment: Go to the page www.codeproject.com they have many public domain win32/MFC projects that will show you how many things work.